# Looking for suggestions on data filtering options in Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project where I want to filter down a lot of data based on user's selections of 8 different criteria.  In my case it's kitchen cabinets but a more universal example would be cars.  The user is presented with a userform containing 8 listboxes, one for Make, Model, Package, Color, Transmission and so on.  Double-clicking on a listbox item removes all other choices in that listbox and filters out invalid choices from all the other listboxes.  The choices compound so the user could choose "Green" for Color and "Ford" for Make.

I've done this two different ways already and I'm not happy with either.

1) I created a matrix where I listed Models down the left hand side and each of the other 7 features across the top with "X" at the intersect points.  Then I taught VBA how to basically read it like a human would using a ton of nested loops.  This was pretty slow, where each selection caused the program to halt for 1-2 minutes while it sorted everything out.

2) I listed out every single possible combination (some 22,000) and used Excel's built in filtering options to filter the data, then copy each column of the results onto a second sheet, filtering out duplicates and re-sorting them, and using that to re-populate the listboxes.  This worked really well but for some reason I can't fathom, Excel gets hung up for 3-10 minutes doing something when I filter certain columns.  I debug/traced it and the hang up happens after all my code is run, but before it returns control to the user.

At this point I'm open to any suggestions.  Ultimately I need the user to choose one complete (all 8 options narrowed down to one choice) configuration.  The tricky part is the user may start with color "Green" which would eliminate all other colors from the "Color" choices list, as well as any Make, or Model, or Package, etc that doesn't come in Green from their respective lists.  Maybe data would help explain it?

```
Make    Model    Package    Color    Transmission
Ford    Focus    LT         Blue     Manual
Ford    Focus    LT         Green    Manual
...
Ford    Focus    ST         Blue     Manual
...
Ford    Focus    LT         Blue     Automatic
...
And so on for 22,000 rows.
```

So if the user chooses "Manual" I need to drop the "Automatic" rows.  If the user then chooses "ST" I need to drop the "LT" rows (while assuming the Automatic rows are still being filtered out, and so on until there's only one row left.

Comment: *Double-clicking on a listbox item removes all other choices*,  *Then I taught VBA* ... What is the wanted end result of all this?

Comment: I need to arrive at a single choice/configuration.  So using the car example, I need the user to narrow it down to "Ford, Focus, LT, Green, Automatic..."  Then I move that selection to a new page and start the process over.  The user can perform this function up to 5 times to compare pricing for 5 different cars/configurations

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea that came to mind: Are you familiar with a highly efficient method of searching for words in a dictionary of words called Trie?
If you code each option properly you could enter the whole option map in a Trie. When a user makes a selection you follow that path in the Trie. If no matching option exist then the Trie returns Null and you can inform the user about that.
Good explanation of a practical Trie implementation for words: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, but it doesn't like this will work as I need to present every option to the user and let them choose one, but the options don't have to be sequential.  Plus this needs to be in VBA for Excel and the example code looks like it's C++, C, Java and Python.